# WPF - ControlTemplate with custom DependencyProperties

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, dependency-properties, controltemplate

I try to give my **ControlTemplate** of the type Button some **DependencyProperties**. For that, I made a class called "ControlButton" and inherited it from Button. I gave this class an empty constructor and tried to connect this class with the style that contains the ControlTemplate.

Here's my **Style** that contains the ControlTemplate:

```
<Style
    TargetType="{x:Type local:ControlButton}"
    x:Key="ControlButton"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FileZip">
    <Setter
        Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate
                TargetType="{x:Type local:ControlButton}">
                <Border>
                    <!-- ... -->
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here is my **class** that should help me to add some **DependencyProperties**. I didn't add DependencyProperties, because I wanted to see if the connection between class and style works:

```
namespace FileZip {
    public partial class ControlButton : Button {
        public ControlButton () : base() {}
    }
}
```

With following code I tried to use my ControlButton

```
<StackPanel
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FileZip">
    <local:ControlButton
        Content="X" />
</StackPanel>
```

Everytime I try to compile my code, Visual Studio returns following two errors:

- "The name 'ControlButton' doesn't exist in the namespace 'FileZip'"
- "Missing XmlNamespace, Assembly, or ClrNamespace in Mapping instruction"

Thanks in advance for your help.

I'm sorry, if my English isn't very good.

Comment: Your `xmlns` declaration should be at the top of the XAML. Not at the control level.

Comment: `FileZip` is in the same assembly where your `XAML` resides or in different assembly?

Comment: At the moment there is only one namespace called FileZip. And this is the name of the assembly too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the section explaining how to apply styles to custom control. Also read the section exampling how to use external assemblies.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295235.aspx